# Eclipse stopped recognizing my Android devices

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've been using Eclipse and testing with 2 devices for the last year w/o a problem. Then all of a sudden today I ran a test of an app and it worked fine, a few hours later though and Eclipse stopped recognizing any device. I switched between my Galaxy S and my old Samsung Acclaim, but neither is working. I tried re-installing the win_usb drivers, I even did a factory reset on the acclaim, and restarted both phones, computer. 
Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Edited:
I looked under device manager and I have a yellow ! on my Samsung Android Composite ADB Interface

ok so I tried to re install the drivers again an error from the installer: Device cannot start

Comment: Make certain that you turned debugging mode back on after you reset the devices.

Comment: Yep usb debugging is turned on

Comment: BTW I'm using Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Ok well it fixed itself I'm not sure how/why. We will see how long it lasts

Comment: If you have a yellow exclamation point, you could try rebooting with driver signature enforcement off. Press F8 at Windows 7 64 bit bootup. Though really it should work or not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing samsung kies, that might help